# numpy - Is possible to construct an ndarray-subclass so that I can slice both the array-object and its array-attribute?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subclass

Instance of `StiffnessMatrix` is basically a 2D-array and one extra 1D-array named `dofs` with **same length** as attribute.

```
class StiffnessMatrix(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array, dofs=None):
        # Input array is an already formed ndarray instance
        # We first cast to be our class type
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.dofs= dofs    
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):

        if obj is None: 
            return

        self.dofs = getattr(obj, 'dofs', None)
```

What I need to do with this is just slice both the `StiffnessMatrix` and `dofs` as below:

```
A = np.eye(4, 4) # random 4x4 array
dofs = np.arange(4) # random 1x4 array 
#Create an instance
OldMatrix = StiffnessMatrix(A, dofs=dofs)

# MY CURRENT WAY
#New view on the instance
NewMatrix = OldMatrix[2:, 2:]
NewMatrix.dofs = OldMatrix.dofs[2:]
NewMatrix.dofs
```

`>> [2, 3]`

Is there a way to make the last operation inside the class, as below?

```
# MY DESIRED WAY    
NewMatrix = OldMatrix[2:, 2:]
NewMatrix.dofs
```

`>> [2, 3]`

I know it sounds boring, and I know there is a way to do it with `pandas`, I am just curious.

Comment: You need to write a `__getitem__` (and `__setitem__`) method - which in turn applies the slicing to both parts.  `MaskedArray` is an example subclass that maintains both a `data` and `mask` values.  It is a good example of how much work it is to write a fully functional subclass.

Comment: thank you I' m going to search it a bit.